# SSL Certificate Warning Breaks IE Automation

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, ssl

I need to automate some actions on CUCM (Cisco Unified Communications Manager), so I'm using PowerShell's `InternetExplorer.Application`.

However, I am seeing an issue relating to an SSL error:

[image]

So following [this tutorial](https://www.kiloroot.com/powershell-script-to-open-a-web-page-and-bypass-ssl-certificate-errors-2/), I first find the **Go on to webpage** link and send a click action - this works great.

However, when the next page loads (where I need to input login details), my script fails to poplulate the login fields with

> The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can 
>   be set.
>   At C:\temp\termTEST\TermForm.ps1:34 char:2
>   +     $document.getelementsbyname("j_username")[0].value = 'sebastian.k ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

But I can confirm that the login field is present, so it seems the `$ie` or `$document` object gets recycles or something similar which means I can't access those fields.

How can I overcome this?

The script:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.navigate("https://10.40.193.31/ccmadmin/phoneFindList.do")
$ie.visible = $true
while ($ie.busy) { sleep 1 }
$global:document = $ie.document
#A while loop to check for IE certificate errors on the page and continue loading the page anyway if there are any
while ($document.readyState -ne 'complete') { sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
if ($document.getelementbyID("overridelink"))
{
    $document.getelementbyid("overridelink").click();
    while ($ie.busy) { sleep 1 }
    $document;
    while ($document.readyState -ne 'complete') { sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
}
#Loading the credentials from the queryCredentials function to log onto the portal
$document.getelementsbyname("j_username")[0].value = 'Bassie' # ERROR OCCURS HERE
$document.getelementsbyname("j_password")[0].value = 'password'
$document.getelementbyid("logonform").submit()
```

If I step through the code manually and physically click the **continue** link (causing the `if` statement to skip), then the login fields are populated just fine, so this is definitely related to the cert error message.

I tried installing the cert onto my machine but for some reason I still get the message. Also contacted our support team to update the certificate but they refuse to help me so I am on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some facts:

1. IE automation will not work unless the website is not trusted (in trusted sites zone) and has a certificate signed by a Trusted Authority
2. Certificates should be given to fqdn or hostname, not ip address
3. Client where IE/Powershell is run, needs to have the Root CA involved in signing chain to be installed in User Certificates > Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

It would be easier if you request and buy an ssl certificate (they are not expensive)

Below is what you can do:

1. Come up with a hostname for this https://10.40.193.31 site, i.e cucm.company.org
2. Create a certificate request csr file and private key, something like below

   openssl req -nodes -new -newkey rsa:4096 -subj '/C=AU/O=Company Limited/CN=cucm.company.org/OU=Phones/L=Sydney/ST=New South Wales/' -keyout cucm.company.org.key -out cucm.company.org.csr
3. Make a request, get issued
4. Follow instructions similar to this to install web server sll cert onto CUCM website: https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/collaboration-voice-and-video/cucm-uploading-ccmadmin-web-gui-certificates/ta-p/3120166
5. Add https://cucm.company.org.csr to trusted sites zone in IE